# interrupt scheduling in .Net Micro Framework

Tags: scheduler, interrupt, interrupt-handling, .net-micro-framework

.NET MF doesn't support preemptive interrupts. Once a process is completed or the 20 msec timer assigned by the scheduler times out, the interrupts can be processed.

Is there any way to change this 20 msec to a shorter time, or change the scheduler process and make it like an real-time scheduler?

Alternatively, assuming the 20 msec delay can be tolerated to begin the interrupt processing, but the exact time of interrupt occurrence at is a must-to-know factor. I think with time argument in an InterruptPort event handler, one can work backwards and determine the time at which the iteruppt got queued.

However, how about if serial port is used, and the time of data arrival to the port must be known? Is there any way that we can determine at what time data arrived to the serial port, or its corresponding interrupt was queued by the framework? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET micro framework was designed to be used on memory constrained micro controllers without an MMU (Memory Management Unit). The .NET Micro framework, even with all its multiple threading model and TCP/IP stack support, does not run on a classical real time operating system structure.

If you need strict real time capability, please check out Windows CE 6.0 R3 and Windows Compact 7 which are hard real time operating systems and have native 32 bit real time support.

Hope my answer helps you.